# Restricting monad type in data constructor

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm looking to create a small monadic interpreter in Haskell and I ran into a problem where GHC is complaining to me that kinds don't match up.

Specifically, here is a declaration for the data type Value:

```
data Value = Wrong
           | Num Int
           | Fun (Value -> Monad Value)
```

and when I compile this, GHC gives the following error message:

```
The first argument of ‘Monad’ should have kind ‘* -> *’,
  but ‘Value’ has kind ‘*’
In the type ‘Value -> (Monad Value)’
In the definition of data constructor ‘Fun’
In the data declaration for ‘Value’
```

But `Monad Value` is of kind `*`. So I don't necessarily see the problem here?

Could anyone kindly point me to the bug that I'm not seeing? Thanks a lot!

P.S. this interpreter is based on the one introduced in Wadler's paper *The essence of functional programming*.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like you want `Fun` to be a wrapper for a function from a `Value` to a monad holding a `Value`. If that's the case you want something like `Fun (Monad m => Value -> m Value)` (I think)

Comment: I tried that, and it complained to me about illegal polymorphic types. Hmm..

Comment: I can't say I'm surprised. It ought to be possible to do something along the lines of `data Monad m => V m = W | N Int | F ( V -> m V )` but I'm not sure if that would fit your needs. This is starting to seem a bit like an XY problem so I would recommend asking on #haskell or something how best to model your interpreter.

Comment: `Monad` has kind `(* -> *) -> Constraint`, so the kind of `Monad x` is `Constraint`, not `*`. Besides that, `Monad Value` is ill-kinded because the kind of `Value` is not `* -> *`, it is `*`. And finally, `Monad` is type class, not a type constructor. Using it in this way is nonsense. You probably want the type `data Value m = ... | Fun (Value m -> m Value)`. Then, just place your `Monad` constraint wherever your data type is used. Trying to place it into the datatype is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, `Monad` expects a type constructor that takes one argument. `Value` is a type constructor that takes no arguments. So, `Value` must have a kind `* -> *` (meaning it takes one argument) instead of `*` (meaning it takes no arguments).

Also, if `Value` did take one argument (allowing this to type check), `Monad Value` is of kind `Constraint`. This is because `Monad` is of kind `(* -> *) -> Constraint` and in `Monad Value` it is being applied to something of kind `* -> *`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I realized that `Value` does need an argument for which kind of monad that the interpreter was using.